# macOS local and remote notifications stopped working – no device token anymore

Tags: swift, macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I developed an app where I am currently debugging issue with remote / local notifications a user have.

My app worked on my site since years like a charm. Now – and I have no clue why (!) my notifications stopped working as well while debugging and pushing out many remote and local notifications. The same problem as the user have occured.

I am using both, remote and local notification. For the remote notification I register as usual but `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` or `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` do not get triggered anymore. None of them. For sure I also do not get my device token for the remote notifications.

Also local notifications do not work anymore (everything worked 2 hours before) – the only thing I switched was the permission request for notifications – but reversed that but still not device token / local notifications.

Are there any limits? But why should a limit keep the app from registering for remote notifications and do not generate the device token.

Really strange behavior that I am not able to solve.

Comment: For remote do you send the device token to your own server?  If so did an SSL expire?

Comment: No, no SSL expired. It has nothing to do with the remote end. The app / device itself di not register anymore for remote notifications. Just do not receive any notifications within this app. On the users site there is a device token again after opening the notebook after a few hours. It feels like a limitation by apple...?

Comment: I disabled automatic signing and selected one of the existing profiles – that worked – strange. So I started from scratch – deleted all older profiles  created a new one for dev and prod, downloaded them, imported them – but then it do not work. In XCode the information panel for the profile shows that push capability is enabled and everything is good. I have recreated all profiles – also revoked all of them, and enabled automatic signing – it do not work...